# detect bluetooth profile of connected state in androd 13

Tags: java, android

upto android 12 bluetooth headset profile connected state is working. when in android 13 its not detecting in connected state once i disconnect and connected it shows bluetooth state but in already connected bluetooth in mobile is not getting bluetooth state.

below code working perfectely upto android 12 but not working for 13. below code works only when bluetooth headphone once connected but not detecting already connected devices.

```
public class HeadsetStateBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver  {

    public static final String[] HEADPHONE_ACTIONS = {
            Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG,
            "android.bluetooth.headset.action.STATE_CHANGED",
            "android.bluetooth.headset.profile.action.CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGED"
    };
    private boolean isaudiostatechanged = false;
    private Headphone_Connection headphoneConnection;
    private static final int STATE_CONNECTED = 0x00000002;
    private static final int STATE_DISCONNECTED = 0x00000000;


    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        String action = intent.getAction(); 


        // Wired headset monitoring

        if (action.equals(HEADPHONE_ACTIONS[0])) {
            int state = intent.getIntExtra("state", -1);

            if (state == 1) {

                int microphone = intent.getIntExtra("microphone", -1);
                if (microphone == 1) {
                    headphoneConnection.onSuccess(true);
                    // Wired headset with microphone is connected
                } else {
                    headphoneConnection.onSuccess(true);
                    // Wired headset without microphone is connected
                }
            } else if (audioManager.isBluetoothA2dpOn() || audioManager.isBluetoothScoOn()) {
                // Bluetooth headset is connected
                Log.d("Headset", "Bluetooth headset is connected");
                headphoneConnection.onSuccess(true);
            } else {
                headphoneConnection.onSuccess(false);
                // Headset is disconnected
            }

        } else if (action.equals(HEADPHONE_ACTIONS[1])) {
            int state = intent.getIntExtra("android.bluetooth.headset.extra.STATE", 0);
            if (state == STATE_CONNECTED) {
                headphoneConnection.onSuccess(true);
            } else if (state == STATE_DISCONNECTED) {
                headphoneConnection.onSuccess(false);
            }
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(HEADPHONE_ACTIONS[2])) {
            int state = intent.getIntExtra("android.bluetooth.profile.extra.STATE", 0);
            if (state == STATE_CONNECTED) {
                headphoneConnection.onSuccess(true);
            } else if (state == STATE_DISCONNECTED) {
                headphoneConnection.onSuccess(false);
            }
        }

        if (audioManager.isWiredHeadsetOn()) {
            // A wired headset is connected
            Log.d("Headset", "Wired headset is connected");
            headphoneConnection.onSuccess(true);
        } else if (audioManager.isBluetoothA2dpOn() || audioManager.isBluetoothScoOn()) {
            // Bluetooth headset is connected
            Log.d("Headset", "Bluetooth headset is connected");
            headphoneConnection.onSuccess(true);
        }


    }

    public void setHeadphoneConnection(Headphone_Connection headphoneConnection) {
        this.headphoneConnection = headphoneConnection;
    }


}
```